# makefile run targets in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I’ve the following makefile, with two rules.

> Is there a way to run these two rules in parallel, I mean to maximize
>   the core’s capabilities? I see this [section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel) but not sure that I got how to use it for my purpose, since I want to handle it within the makefile and not from the command line.

I.e. run module1 & 2 targets in parallel.

This is the makefile:

```
all: module1 module2

.PHONY: module1
module1:
    @echo "run module 1"
    DIR=$(PWD)
    @echo $(DIR)

.PHONY: module2
module2:
    @echo "run module2”

cleanup: 
    fzr clean $(DIR)
```

Comment: What about `make -j2` is not working?

Comment: Probably OP is unfamiliar. Checkout the [man](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html).

Comment: @Thomas - as I write in the question , I want to do it within the file and not with command, how can I do it ?

Comment: @kabanus - im familiar with this option as it written in the doc i've provided , but my question is a bit different , I want to somehow do it from the file

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot invoke `make` with the job flag?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set `make` options that you usually pass to make via its command line invokation in the makefile itself. Add this line to your makefile

```
MAKEFLAGS += -j2
```

and you can invoke `make` without the `-j` flag, it will still spawn two processes to build targets in parallel, when they aren't dependent on each other. To automatically determine the number of jobs to spawn, you can use this on linux

```
NPROCS = $(shell grep -c 'processor' /proc/cpuinfo)
MAKEFLAGS += -j$(NPROCS)
```

and on MacOS

```
NPROCS = $(shell sysctl hw.ncpu  | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
MAKEFLAGS += -j$(NPROCS)
```

Comment: thanks but this is someting that I see in the docs, what I need it to do it within the file as I write in the question and not by command, how it can be done ?

Comment: I adjusted the answer.

Comment: thanks , 1+, is there way to determine how much process I can run ?because it's different for each machine ...

Comment: This works on a Mac `sysctl hw.ncpu`. On Linux try `lscpu`

Comment: `nproc` is better for this than `lscpu`; it will give ju just the number.

Comment: @Biffen - can you show how to use it with the flags in the makefile ? the `nproc`

Comment: @shopiaT `MAKEFLAGS += -j$(shell nproc || printf 1)` (`|| printf 1` so that if `nproc` isn’t available you’ll get a `1`).

Comment: @lubgr thanks a lot , ill try it now ,is it possible also in windows machine ?

Comment: @lugbr - just to verify in case I use the code you have provided and I use `echo` for MAKEFLAGS and I got `--jobserver-fds=3,4 -j` what does this numbers `3,4` is ?

Comment: Same behavior here. It seems to be an undocumented internal detail of the jobserver functionality, you can read about it [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47392) or [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/).

Comment: @lubgr - but what is actually mean, it wil run in 3 process ?

Comment: @lubgr - or 4 process , i've core i7 (2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 just as an example... )

Comment: No, it works as expected, the parameters following `--jobserver-fds` don't reflect the number of processes. I just checked it with similar `module3` and `module4` targets and manually changing the `NPROCS` variable.

Comment: @lubgr - so how can I know how much process I have to run the makefile ? I've tried with `@echo $(MAKEFLAGS)` should I do it in other way?

Comment: Go with `@echo $(NPROCS)`.

Comment: This is great, but the fact that it runs 3 or 4 in the same shell, that's not so fun. As the output becomes pretty much useless since it starts mashing up. Would be great if it was forking processes with separate outputs.

Comment: This is pretty far afield, but w.r.t. @logicbloke, try `--output-sync=target` on GNU make 4+.

Answer (score 0):

Even a `MAKEFLAGS += -j$(NPROCS)` would *not* work if you have '::' instead of ':' for your rule, as illustrated by that recent fix in Git 2.25.2 (March 2020)

See [commit 2607d39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2607d39da347e207ecb972300cdb8b82f6772d3b) (18 Feb 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 29b09c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29b09c518c93e916bc91758d4cebe86b56f43040), 02 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`doc-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2607d39da347e207ecb972300cdb8b82f6772d3b): use single-colon rule in rendering Makefile
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> When rendering the troff manpages to text via "man", we create an ad-hoc Makefile and feed it to "`make`".
>   The purpose here is two-fold:
>
> - reuse results from a prior interrupted render of the same tree
> - use make's `-j` option to build in parallel
>
> **But the second part doesn't seem to work (at least with my version of GNU make, 4.2.1). It just runs one render at a time.**
>
> We use a double-colon "`all`" rule for each file, like:
>
> ```
> all:: foo
> foo:
>   ...actual render recipe...
> all:: bar
> bar:
>   ...actual render recipe...
> ...and so on...
> ```
>
> **And it's this double-colon that seems to inhibit the parallelism**.
>   We can just switch to a regular single-colon rule.
>
> Even though we do have multiple rules for "all" here, we don't have any recipe to execute for "all" (we only care about triggering its dependencies), so the distinction is irrelevant.