# Build time inside the RHEL 7 VM (VirtualBox)

Tags: virtualbox, build-time

ALL,

I have a software that I'm trying to build on both host machine and VirtualBox client.

Both machine use the same RHEL7 OS and exctly the same set of Makefile's.

However the build time on the host is much faster than on VM.

Is there a way to improve the build time so it can at least be comparable with the host one?

TIA!!

Comment: In general - no, you have hypervisor overhead which emulates hardware. I think a bit of improvement can give assigning more CPUs on Virtualbox and run targets in parallel - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148963/makefile-run-targets-in-parallel.

Comment: @TelinovDmitri, well I have 4 processors assigned and I am running `make -j8`. I was hoping I can do something else to do, because the build time is almost x3 now.